# Java android - ImageView scrolling causes crashing?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have a function which is meant to scroll my **Image-view** so that it falls 5 pixels every 0.1 seconds, however as soon as I run this function I get `Sorry Application has stopped responding`

You can check my code below.:

```
    void startGameLoop(){
    boolean alive=true;
    while(alive){

        int x = theSprite.getScrollX();
        int y = theSprite.getScrollY();
        y-=5;
        theSprite.scrollTo(x, y);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: please add logcat! Looks like an eternal loop to me so far. I mean when will be `alive == false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this code `Thread.sleep(100);` on the main thread that will happen.
Use a Handler with delay instead. The handler can change things like `ImageView` because it operates on the main Ui Thread.
Something like this..

```
private final Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int x = theSprite.getScrollX();
        int y = theSprite.getScrollY();
        y-=5;
        theSprite.scrollTo(x, y);
        if (!closing)
            startTimer();
    }
};

handler = new Handler();
startTimer();

/**
 * Start periodically callbacks.
 */
private void startTimer() {
    runOnUiThreadDelay(timerRunnable, 400L);
}

public void runOnUiThreadDelay(final Runnable runnable, long delayMillis) {
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayMillis);
}
```

Comment: Surely there's be a way to do this with sleep? Your method of doing this seems extremely complicated, plus I don't seem to be able to get it to work I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: Nop, if you sleep on the main thread your app will sleep. Handler with delay is not sleeping on the main ui thread. It's a thread and it's allowed to change things in the UI. Just put the `handler = new Handler(); and startTimer();` in your oncreate() and it will start every 400mili